# Zoom in and out like Email

Tags: android

I have tried to research for around 1/2 hour but without success. I'm experienced in **java** but new to **Android development**.

I'm trying to produce an activity that contains pictures and text that can be zoomed in and out. The email application can do this but my searching keeps showing those who have problems with their email.

My question is 'please point me to the correct section of the android developers help that comes with the SDK'. Or if this is highly advanced then please advise this.

Thanks for any response as this is my first post

Comment: No email app (gmail) does not support zoom in-out. Perhaps you are using a different email client. Furthermore, zooming in normal views is not straightforward for beginners. Usually, zoomable content is inside a webview, which has build in support for zooming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to zoom in and out use WebView

[See this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

you can enable zooming easily [refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29)

Comment: Hi, tried this and thanks but on my Sony Xperia U (ICS) the zoom does not work (does it need Chrome?) Also can the web pages be stored in the application?